# How to set dialect in mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate

[image]
I got these exceptions while connecting to the Mysql DB using hibernate
please give me solution for this exceptions

Comment: Please post your exception messages **as text** by **editing** your post.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing MySQL `Connector/J` [jar](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html) from the `lib` folder. You can download it and include it in the dependencies (lib) in order to make Hibernate connect/interact with MySQL db.

[Here](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/writing-a-basic-hibernate-based-program-with-eclipse?start=1) are the steps of how to do it.